# How to post a data using Plain Javascript fetch on Laravel?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, fetch

I made this method on my javascript to post data into my database:

```
if(document.getElementById('approve_leave_request')){
    document.getElementById('approve_leave_request').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        const urlReq = window.location.origin+"/leave/customize";
        const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');

        const leave = {
            status: 'Approved',
        };

        const request = new Request(urlReq, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(leave),
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token
            })
        });

        fetch(request).then(res => res.json()).then(res => console.log(res));

    })
}
```

and this is my controller function:

```
public function customize_update(Request $request){
    return response()->json(['message'=>'Called successfully.']);
}
```

and on my api:

```
Route::post('leave/customize', 'LeaveController@customize_update')->name('api.leave.customize');
```

but during execution i am getting this error:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/leave/customize 405 (Method Not Allowed)
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: Is not your route supposed to be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/leave/customize` ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake yeah thats ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/leave/customize```.